# How can I call a Meteor template event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, jasmine, meteor-velocity

Functionality: A user has to enter a lecture code into an input field to enter a lecture. On the landing page, while the user types the lecture code, I want check if the code is correct and colour the "btn-enter-lecture" green if it is.

```
'keyup #lecture-code-input' : function() {
    var possibleLectureID = $('#lecture-code-input').val();
    var possibleLecture = Lectures.findOne({lectureCode: possibleLectureID});
    if(possibleLecture){
        $('#btn-enter-lecture').addClass('btn-success');
        $('#btn-enter-lecture').removeClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#btn-enter-lecture').removeClass('btn-success');
        $('#btn-enter-lecture').addClass('disabled');
    }
}
```

To test this functionality with jasmine I paste the lecture code into the input field and try to trigger the event with jquery. But this will not call the meteor event.

```
describe("'Enter Class' button", function() {
    it("turns green when there is a lecture with this lecture code", function(done) {
        $('#lecture-code-input').val(lectureCode);
        $('#lecture-code-input').trigger('keyup');
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if(!$('button#btn-enter-class').hasClass('disabled')){
                clearInterval(interval);
                expect($('button#btn-enter-class').hasClass('btn-success')).toBe(true);
                done();
            }
        },5);
    });
});
```

How can I trigger this meteor template event to test if the button turns green afterwards?

Code: https://github.com/minden/rewind/commit/cac61ecc3da3014548ad4ec9d1ceb2fd49bb265c

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial: https://doctorllama.wordpress.com/2014/09/22/bullet-proof-internationalised-meteor-applications-with-velocity-unit-testing-integration-testing-and-jasmine/

Go all the way down to: ".registerForTutorial"

You should see this:

```
var data = new Tutorial();

spyOn(data, "registerStudent");
spyOn(Blaze, "getData").and.returnValue(data);

Template.tutorials.__eventMaps[0]["click .registerForTutorial"].call({templateInstance: function() {}}, {preventDefault : function() {}});

expect(data.registerStudent).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I think that is what you are looking for. You need to specify the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the sample [Leaderboard Tests](https://github.com/awatson1978/leaderboard-tinytests/blob/master/leaderboard-tests.js)

Here's a snippet from the link

```
Tinytest.add('Template.leaderboard [click input.inc] event', function (test) {

  //updates the player score by 5 when input.inc is clicked
  Session.set('selected_player', 1234);
  Players.update = function (selector, options) {
      test.equal(selector, 1234);
      test.equal(options.$inc.score, 5);
  };
  Template.leaderboard.fireEvent('click input.inc');
});
```